Image plane Invisible when in front of objects
I am using Blender 4.3. I added an image as a background using an empty. The image is invisible when in front of other objects.


What about the Depth setting in the Data panel ? Above where you set the image path.

@Lutzi I think that this is the answer

@Lutzi Thank you, this is the correct answer. If you want to make an answer, I will mark correct.
